# tor browser 4.5, change proxy settings

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, network-configuration, i2p, proxy

I use Tor Browser for I2P. In the new version 4.5 I can't find TorButton. How do I change the proxy settings for using i2p, http 4444 etc. I don't want to disable it because "TBB has a Torbutton extension that "disables many types of active content " right now im just testing in `about:config` how to deal with this. I also want to know the risk of changing proxy settings.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the settings in `about:config`. Just enter it into the address bar and read+confirm the warning. When the config page is open, search for `network.proxy`. You'll see `network.proxy.socks_port` set to 9150. You can double-click on `network.proxy.http_port` and set it to 4444. You should also make some settings for other proxies.

When you're changed the settings, Tor Browser will immediately use it.